# Looping dictionaries from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, python-itertools

I am trying to create ts dictionary from Pandas table but I couldn't achieve it.

**My table:**

```
         Bool       name       station_id           Coords
0        True       item1          1        19.28152437,47.78960029
1        True       item2          2        20.15190158,46.25528206
```

**My desired output:**

```
a= {
    'item1':[ 19.28152437,47.78960029],
    'item2':[20.15190158,46.25528206],
}
```

**I am using iterrows to do it:**

```
for i, c in allomasok.iterrows():
     //here is the problem, I can't add name of the dict item
```

Comment: The values in the list in the dictionary `a` are not present in the example above. `b` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself. Can you clarify your question and maybe contextualize it ?  If you want to use non mutable iterable objects you could try using tuples

Comment: I corrected it, sorry of my typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.set_index` combined with `pd.DataFrame.to_dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['item1', 'item2'],
                   'Coord': ['19.28152437,47.78960029', '20.15190158,46.25528206']})

df['Coord'] = df['Coord'].apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x.split(','))))
d = df.set_index('name')['Coord'].to_dict()

# {'item1': [19.28152437, 47.78960029], 'item2': [20.15190158, 46.25528206]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got this from my `DataFrame: {'item1': '16.09016385, 46.74074716 ', 'item2': '17.00062128, 46.46736962 '}`. The table above is a left-joined table, so the table is already a DataFrame.

Comment: I edited my question. I typed wrong coordinates, but the querstion is: How can I create the desired output from the two column (name, Coords) of my Pandas DataFrame table.